# Rough Volatility Prediction - Gatheral, Jaisson, Rosenbaum Paper

Tags: volatility, stochastic-volatility

I just read through the paper "Volatility Is Rough" by Gatheral, Jaisson and Rosenbaum. There is a website (link: http://tpq.io/p/rough_volatility_with_python.html) that details the simulations they have done in their paper which I found quite useful. There is one point, however, where I seem to miss something. They are approximating the prediction formula (5.1 in the paper) via its Riemann sum but they drop the term $\frac{cos(H\pi)}{\pi}$. Any reason why? Apologies if this is obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, weird... I see this term appearing in both your link and the original paper: https://mfe.baruch.cuny.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/RoughVolatilityColumbia2018.pdf
Maybe they updated it?

Answer (score 1):

1) They drop the
$$ \frac{\cos (H\pi)}{\pi} \cdot \Delta^{H + 1/2}$$

2) They divide by a normalization factor, which is the sum of the integrand (without the $\log v_s$).

If you integrate:
$$ \frac{\cos (H\pi)}{\pi} \cdot \Delta^{H + 1/2} \cdot \frac{1}{(x + \Delta) \cdot x^{H + 1/2}}$$
from zero to infinity, you will get 1.

Comment: Thank you skoestlmiere.  I'm wondering if you could guide me on how to write formulas/equations.  I did not see an option to "insert formula" when writing my response.  Thank you